# Random Forest class probabilities in seperate raster layers

Tags: r, probability, random-forest, raster, r-raster

I'm using the randomForest package to classify a raster stack of different predictors. Classification works fine, but I also want to retrieve the class probabilities. With my code I only get a RasterLayer with the probability of the first class, but I'd like to get a RasterStack with the class probabilities for each class in one layer.

```
PRED_train$response <- as.factor(PRED_train$response)
rf <- randomForest(response~., data = PRED_train, na.action = na.omit, confusion = T)

pred_RF <- raster::predict(PRED,rf,)
beginCluster()
pred_RF <- clusterR(PRED, predict, args = list(rf,type="prob"))
endCluster()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first place to look should be `?raster::predict`; which has an example that shows how to do that. Here it is:

```
library(raster)
logo <- brick(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster"))
p <- matrix(c(48, 48, 48, 53, 50, 46, 54, 70, 84, 85, 74, 84, 95, 85, 
   66, 42, 26, 4, 19, 17, 7, 14, 26, 29, 39, 45, 51, 56, 46, 38, 31, 
   22, 34, 60, 70, 73, 63, 46, 43, 28), ncol=2)
a <- matrix(c(22, 33, 64, 85, 92, 94, 59, 27, 30, 64, 60, 33, 31, 9,
   99, 67, 15, 5, 4, 30, 8, 37, 42, 27, 19, 69, 60, 73, 3, 5, 21,
   37, 52, 70, 74, 9, 13, 4, 17, 47), ncol=2)

xy <- rbind(cbind(1, p), cbind(0, a))
v <- data.frame(cbind(pa=xy[,1], extract(logo, xy[,2:3])))
v$pa <- as.factor(v$pa)

library(randomForest)
rfmod <- randomForest(pa ~., data=v)
rp <- predict(logo, rfmod, type='prob', index=1:2)
spplot(rp)
```

Comment: adding index = <number of classes as vector> will do the job