# Plotting uncertainty from raster predictions

Tags: r, raster, prediction, landscape, uncertainty

I'm using the predict function from the raster package to predict species occurrence from a raster brick in R using a previously fitted model. Prediction plot works fine, and now I'm trying to create a corresponding plot of prediction uncertainty at each point (basically a map of uncertainty). The predict.lm function in the stats package has an interval option, but I don't see anything like that in the raster predict function. Are there any workarounds to accomplish this?

```
library(embarcadero)
library(sp)
library(raster)
library(nnet)

# fit model
sdm <- bart.step(x.data = all.cov[,xvars], 
                 y.data = all.cov[,'a.amphibius'], 
                 full = TRUE,
                 quiet = TRUE)

# spatial prediction
hytr.layer <- predict(object = sdm,
  x.layers = covs,
  splitby = 20,
  quiet = TRUE)

# prediction plot
plot(hytr.layer,
     box = FALSE,
     axes = FALSE,
     main = 'A. amphibius',
     zlim = c(0,1),
     axis.args=list(at=pretty(0:1), labels=pretty(0:1)),
     legend.args=list(text='Probability', side=2, line=1.3))
```

Comment: This answer might be useful, depending on the model being used to predict the raster: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55291512/9022665

Comment: It can be done if there is such a method, or you can come up with one, for the model created with `bart.step`.